# Jenkins master holding back slave results

Tags: jenkins, gerrit

There are five jobs in sequential order(1,2,3,4,5). Jobs 2,3,4,5 are built successfully(but they have not come out of the execution shell), since the job 1 is still compiling. If I abort job 1 then all the results of 2,3,4,5 are updated spontaneously to gerrit.

How can I change this configuration in Jenkins master?

Comment: How can the jobs be in sequential order when job1 is still running and jobs 2-5 are already build successfully?

Comment: All 1-5 jobs are related to a specific branch, and since it a multiple slave setup so 2-5 got executed on different slaves.

Comment: Ok, so they are not sequential. Are the jobs 2-5 somehow connected to job1 (e.g. job1 executes 2-5 and waits for them to finish)?

Comment: No they are not connected except that all the jobs are related to one branch

Comment: I would guess it is an gerrit issue or an integration issue with gerrit.

Comment: I'm suspecting Jenkins master, as the master would have distributed jobs in sequence and so he's expecting the results in the same order.

Comment: I am using Jenkins with lots of slaves. The jobs are completely independent. They may or may not  check out the same code. They finish whenever they are done. no update issue is present. However, I don't integrate with gerrit. I don't know what the limitations of gerrit are. I would not expect the Master to be the culprit, I think it is more likely the integration with gerrit. You might want to file a bug report with the plugin developers. They should be in the best position to say if it is a plugin or master issue. It might just be a simple limitation of gerrit api as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug in the Jenkins mailer plugin, you need to upgrade the plugin to the latest version.

Here you can find more details:

- [Github - [FIXED JENKINS-20867] Never wait for a prior build to
  complete merely](https://github.com/jenkinsci/mailer-plugin/commit/a32b1f191ed7b4fd93f6d8905604314c8992654a)
- [Jenkins - Sending mail blocks on prior build](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-20867)